# Is the DYNAMO code developed by LAMMPS still available?

Tags: software, reference-request, lammps

[In 2013 it was stated that v8.8 of DYNAMO was the version mostly used](https://sourceforge.net/p/lammps/mailman/message/30731504/) for the last 10-12 years.

However I am struggling to find the code repository. It was developed by the LAMMPS developers and is used to mix eam potentials.

DYNAMO was available on sourceforge.net, but now it seems to have been removed. Where can I get access to the repository?

Comment: Can you send us a link to the SourceForce page? I looked up "dynamo lammps" but the first few results were from 2014 at the latest. Is this code still actively maintained?

Comment: The link is taken down. Anybody who has it downloaded can upload it again. The code isn't maintained actively on any website. Also, search for "dynamO mixing potential" instead of "dynamO lammps" for better clarity of what dynamo is.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is Steve Plimpton. So far as I know there
is no official DYNAMO website or download location.
The code long pre-dates the popularity of source code "repositories".  It
was developed by Daw and Foiles (mentioned in the thread),
two or the originators of EAM potentials.
That said, I do have a tarball I can send you 
if you contact me via my work email - I'm at Sandia Labs.
I'm not sure what DYNAMO version it is.

As was mentioned, we put many DYNAMO features
into ParaDyn which we wrote to allow EAM models
to run in parallel, but that was in the 1990s
and DYNAMO may have evolved since then.  And as was
also said, the parallel LAMMPS MD code includes the
original EAM (a la DYNAMO) and a variety of EAM
variants, including MEAM (modified EAM) and some
angular-dependent versions.  LAMMPS is actively supported
and has its own mail list where you can ask further questions.

Hope that helps,
Steve

Answer (score 14):

There is a page on the [Sandia labs website](https://www.sandia.gov/%7Esjplimp/download.html) that includes download links for all the software developed by Steve Plimpton. It sounds as if he reimplemented all the functionality of DYNAMO into a program called ParaDyn (the para denoting that it was modified to run in parallel).

Alternatively, the site makes it sound as though *almost all* the features of DYNAMO have also already been incorporated into LAMMPS and are even faster than in ParaDyn. So you may just be able to use LAMMPS instead.

If you really do need DYNAMO, I would suggest contacting [Murray Daw](https://www.clemson.edu/science/departments/physics-astro/people/daw.html) or [Stephen Foiles](https://www.sandia.gov/cgi-bin/emplloc?ename=foiles) who originally developed the program and may know what has become of it.

Comment: +1. Well researched! I searched a bit but didn't get as far as you. That webpage of Steve Plimpton's that you linked, doesn't actually say "dynamo" anywhere, so kudos to you for discovering ParaDyn!

Comment: @NikeDattani I came across ParaDyn in the documentation for LAAMPS and once I knew to look for "paradyn sandia" it wasn't too hard to find. In the description for ParaDyn, it does briefly mention its relationship to DYNAMO.

Comment: I see! Have you worked with these before, or did you just do this research to answer this question?

Comment: @NikeDattani just did some Googling for this question.

Answer (score 10):

I should also mention that there are several repositories on the web of interatomic potentials, which include many, many EAM files
for different materials.  These are the files that a code like DYNAMO
or LAMMPS reads in, with tabulated values for the EAM functionals, not code implementations of the EAM equations.

This doc page in the LAMMPS manual, lists several of them:
https://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/pair_eam.html

The last one on the list for the OpenKIM project, is a good place to start.

Steve